# Can't access child elements in XML

Tags: python, xml

I was trying to parse a string in XML format into some plain python objects, and I tried to use the `find` and `findall` methods to access some child elements but it doesn't work .

Here is the XML data I'am trying to parse :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ItemSearchResponse
    xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">

    <Items>
        <Request>
            <IsValid>True</IsValid>
            <ItemSearchRequest>
                <Keywords>iphone</Keywords>
                <ResponseGroup>ItemAttributes</ResponseGroup>
                <SearchIndex>All</SearchIndex>
            </ItemSearchRequest>
        </Request>
        <TotalResults>40721440</TotalResults>
        <TotalPages>4072144</TotalPages>

        <Item>
            <ASIN>B00YV50QU4</ASIN>
            <ParentASIN>B018GTHAKO</ParentASIN>
            <DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-MD439LL-Smartphone-Refurbished/dp/B00YV50QU4%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIEEA4BKMTHTI2T7A%26tag%3Dshopit021-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00YV50QU4</DetailPageURL>
            <ItemLinks>

            </ItemLinks>
            <ItemAttributes>
            </ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ASIN>B00VHSXBUA</ASIN>
            <ParentASIN>B0152TROY8</ParentASIN>
            <ItemAttributes>
            </ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

I've deleted some data, in order to make this sample shorter .

And here is my code .

```
data  = et.fromstring(response)
            items = data[0][3]
            print items.tag
            items = data[0].findall('item')
            print len(items.findall('.//item'))
```

The first way to access child nodes ('item') is to use the list index notation, and it's working fine. But using the find all method it's not working and the `len()` always return 0 .

I've tried to use XPath and other ways, but using the index is the only way to get it work .

Why methods like `find` and `findall` don't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why methods like find and findall don't work ?

Because there are no elements named `Item`.  Your document defines a default XML namespace of `http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01`, which means that an element that looks like `<Item>` in your document is actually contained in that namespace and is *different* from an element that looks like `<Item>` in a document without a default XML namespace (or with a different XML namespace).

You want something like:

```
>>> ns = 'http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01'
>>> items = data[0].findall('{%s}Item' % ns)
>>> items
[<Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Item at 0x7f1cbaaba8c0>, <Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Item at 0x7f1cbaaba680>]
```

Or, using XPath:

```
>>> items = data[0].xpath('n:Item', namespaces={'n': ns})
>>> items
[<Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Item at 0x7f1cbaaba8c0>, <Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}Item at 0x7f1cbaaba680>]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you've saved some long nights of debugging :)